# How to display images on two sides of content using html/css?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and working on a page that I would like to render as shown below -

[image: Sample Web Page]

How do I write css so that the content stays in the center while images floats vertically on left and right side of it?

Comment: Encourage: you should use Flex Items CSS3 to display multi-effects http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images in containers, then apply `position: absolute`.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1024px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120">
  </div>
  <div class="container">Main content</div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got the hint I needed, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floating columns as in a grid system such as Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation. Then you can make it responsive as well. I recommend Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html